# Count total of entries by 1 user from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL Select statement that will tell me the total number of practices and the total number of shows that an artist has logged.
I have 3 tables, Artists, Practices and Shows.

The Practices and Shows tables have a Artist_ID in them as a foreign key, as well as their own auto-incremented IDs and a date column. I'm trying to count the total number of practices and the total number of shows that each user has.

I've tried several statements.. this is the latest attempt.

```
SELECT COUNT(P.Practice_ID) as NumberOfPractices, COUNT(S.Show_ID) as NumberOfShows
FROM Practices P                                                                      
INNER JOIN Artists A ON P.Artist_ID = A.Artist_ID
RIGHT JOIN Shows S ON A.Artist_ID = S.Artist_ID
WHERE A.Artist_ID = :artistID
```

This, and evertying else I've tried seems to be multiplying the amounts of the two tables. For example, the Practices should equal 21 and the Shows 2. But I'm getting 42 as the result for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT OUTER JOIN is being used as an artist can have 0 Shows or Practises.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.Practice_ID) as NumberOfPractices, COUNT(DISTINCT S.Show_ID) as NumberOfShows
FROM Artists A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Practices P ON P.Artist_ID = A.Artist_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Shows S ON A.Artist_ID = S.Artist_ID
WHERE A.Artist_ID = :artistID
GROUP BY A.Artist_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I'm getting the same thing I was before.. a multiplied result of the two.

Comment: missed out on DISTINCT. Have added it now. Can you check

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT
     a.Artist_ID
     , COUNT(p.Practice_ID)
     , COUNT(s.Show_ID)

    FROM
     Artists a
    LEFT JOIN
     Practice p
    ON a.Artist_ID = p.Artist_ID
    LEFT JOIN
     Shows s
    ON a.Artist_ID = s.Artist_ID

    GROUP BY
     a.Artist_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Close.  Your problem is a Cartesian join -- which is why both counts are returning the same value.

The simplest solution is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.Practice_ID) as NumberOfPractices,
       COUNT(DISTINCT S.Show_ID) as NumberOfShows
FROM Practices P                                                                      
INNER JOIN Artists A ON P.Artist_ID = A.Artist_ID
RIGHT JOIN Shows S ON A.Artist_ID = S.Artist_ID
WHERE A.Artist_ID = :artistID;
```

However, I recommend simplifying the code:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.Practice_ID)
        FROM Practices p
        WHERE p.Artist_ID = :artistID
       ) as NumberOfPractices,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.Show_ID)
        FROM Shows s
        WHERE s.Artist_ID = :artistID
       ) as NumberOfShows
```

You don't even need the `Artists` table.

Comment: This worked. I tried your 2nd suggestion, to simplify, but for whatever reason it didn't work out.

Comment: @user3498517 . . . That is rather vague.  How did it not work?

Comment: I don't know... it just didn't return a result. And I got a 500 error in the console. I noticed the P is capitalized when it shouldn't be. But I fixed that and it was still the same... no result 500 error. FYI, I'm using this with ajax, so I'm expecting a result to be returned, not printed... but this gave nothing except the error in the console.

Comment: @user3498517 . . . Very odd.  This should be the most efficient method.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I plugged this directly into my PHP Myadmin and it worked... not sure why I'm not getting a result through ajax though, I'm getting results from other Queries just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your query is you started with practice table which is a child table (can contain duplicate artist_id). When joined with artist table you introduced duplicate artist_id's in intermediate result set for a.artist_id column.

```
SELECT COUNT(P.Practice_ID) as NumberOfPractices, COUNT(S.Show_ID) as 
NumberOfShows
FROM Practices P                                                                      
INNER JOIN Artists A ON P.Artist_ID = A.Artist_ID --> here you introduced duplicates
RIGHT JOIN Shows S ON A.Artist_ID = S.Artist_ID 
WHERE A.Artist_ID = :artistID
```

To avoid duplicates I recommend to start with master table (artist) which has unique artist_id, and use the it to join child tables.

```
SELECT a.artist_id, COUNT(p.practice_id) as NumberOfPractices, 
count(s.show_id) as NumberOfShows 
FROM artists a
LEFT JOIN practices p ON (a.artist_id = p.artist_id)
LEFT JOIN shows s ON (a.artist_id = s.artist_id)
GROUP BY a.artist_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just gives me the multiplied results I was getting before.